# How I can define a window in spark sql. With fixed size; start with it's min value; non-overlapping

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to define a window whose range depends on the value, but the range is fixed( for example 3). But the starting value of the window depends on the smallest possible value. And each window does not overlap each other.

For example

1. my sequence is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, then I get the window as `[1,2,3]`, `[4,5,6]`, `[7]`.
2. my sequence is `[1,2,3,3,5,6,7]`, then the window I get is `[1,2,3,3]`, `[5,6,7]`. The 2nd window start by elem `5`, because the 1st window range is [1, 1+3=4), and 5 is the smallest value in this sequence that is greater than or equal to 4, so its used as the starting point for the second window, and the 2nd window range is [5, 5+3=8), so 7 is in the 2nd window.
3. my sequence is `[1,2,3,3,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,10,20]` then I get the window as `[1,2,3,3]`, `[5,6,7,7,7,7,7]`, `[10]`, `[20]`.

The data is a batch-dataframe(not streaming) in Spark, and my current difficulty is: how to determine the starting point of the subsequent window. As of now, I'd like to do as much as possible through the Spark-Sql-API, but the Code-API idea would also work.

Spark version: 3.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can use [session_window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.session_window.html) function to separate islands of data more than 3 numbers apart. Tricky part is that it only works on timestamps, so you'll need to derive a dummy timestamp column from integer using [from_unixtime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime.html).

Then within each group calculate [dense_rank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html) and get groups 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, etc. - ie. integer divide by 3.

Finally rank again on the islands and groups.

Putting it all together:

```sql
WITH
  data AS (
    -- Data to play with and derived timestamp
    SELECT explode(array(1,2,3,3,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,10,20)) as i,
           from_unixtime(i) as t
  ),
  session AS (
    -- Here we calculate groups/islands using session_window
    SELECT min(i) as min_i, max(i) as max_i,
           row_number() over (order by 1) as session
      FROM data
     GROUP BY session_window(t, '2 seconds') -- note it's 2 seconds, not 3
  )
SELECT i, dense_rank() over (order by session, session_group) as total_group
  FROM (SELECT i, session,
               floor((dense_rank() over (partition by session order by i) - 1) / 3) as session_group
          FROM data
          JOIN session ON i between min_i and max_i);

+--+-----------+
|i |total_group|
+--+-----------+
|1 |1          |
|2 |1          |
|3 |1          |
|3 |1          |
|5 |2          |
|6 |2          |
|7 |2          |
|7 |2          |
|7 |2          |
|7 |2          |
|7 |2          |
|7 |2          |
|7 |2          |
|10|3          |
|20|4          |
+--+-----------+
```

It looks a bit hacky, but works :) Note that it might have problems on large datasets due to windowing functions without partitions. Maybe there's room for some optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Range start can be detected by comparing with previous value, and range start assigned to each row. Then range sliced with slice size, and slices joined with original data:

```
val sliceSize = 3
val df = Seq(
  1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 20
).toDF()


val orderedWindow = Window.orderBy($"value")
val rankedWindow = orderedWindow.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
val isRangeStart = $"value" - coalesce(lag($"value", 1).over(orderedWindow), lit(-1)) > 1

val ranges = df
  .distinct()
  .withColumn("isRangeStart", isRangeStart)
  .withColumn("rangeStart", max(
    when($"isRangeStart", $"value").otherwise(0)
  ).over(rankedWindow))
  .withColumn("sliceNo", floor(($"value" - $"rangeStart") / sliceSize))

ranges.show(false)

// slicing ranges
val slices = ranges
  .groupBy("rangeStart", "sliceNo")
  .agg(
    min($"value").alias("sliceStart"),
    max($"value").alias("sliceEnd")
  )
  .select("sliceStart", "sliceEnd")
  .distinct()

slices.show(false)

// join
df.alias("d")
  .join(slices.alias("s"), $"d.value".between($"s.sliceStart", $"s.sliceEnd"))
  .select($"value", $"sliceStart".alias("groupId"))
```

Output:

```
+-----+------------+----------+-------+
|value|isRangeStart|rangeStart|sliceNo|
+-----+------------+----------+-------+
|1    |true        |1         |0      |
|2    |false       |1         |0      |
|3    |false       |1         |0      |
|5    |true        |5         |0      |
|6    |false       |5         |0      |
|7    |false       |5         |0      |
|10   |true        |10        |0      |
|20   |true        |20        |0      |
+-----+------------+----------+-------+

+----------+--------+
|sliceStart|sliceEnd|
+----------+--------+
|1         |3       |
|5         |7       |
|10        |10      |
|20        |20      |
+----------+--------+

+-----+-------+
|value|groupId|
+-----+-------+
|1    |1      |
|2    |1      |
|3    |1      |
|3    |1      |
|5    |5      |
|6    |5      |
|7    |5      |
|7    |5      |
|7    |5      |
|7    |5      |
|7    |5      |
|7    |5      |
|7    |5      |
|10   |10     |
|20   |20     |
+-----+-------+
```