# Dynamically create and label fixed-size buckets based on row values

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I'd like to be able to assign rows to buckets / ranges that start at the first occurrence of an event that isn't within another bucket, and are always of a fixed size (let's say in minutes).

For example, given some events that happen over this timeline, with a bucket size of 3, the following buckets should exist (buckets are inclusive, inclusive):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...  -- time as minutes
  a b       b a b b      -- events
  |___|     |___| |___|  -- buckets
```

The algorithm could be described as:

- When seeing an event:

  - If not in a bucket, start a bucket that lasts 3 minutes and assign event to bucket
  - If in a current bucket, just assign event to bucket

Additionally, I need the bucket to be marked with the name of the event that caused the bucket to be created.

So, this data (from the above diagram):

```
 value | time
-------|------
 a     | 1
 b     | 2
 b     | 6
 a     | 7
 b     | 8
 b     | 9
```

Should result in this result:

```
 value | time | bucket_value
-----------------------------
 a     | 1    | a
 b     | 2    | a
 b     | 6    | b
 a     | 7    | b
 b     | 8    | b
 b     | 9    | b
```

I've mainly tried to think of ways to figure out the state per row and annotate using that. I've also tried to merge contiguous / overlapping ranges and then split them evenly by required bucket size, but to no avail.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77184778/how-i-can-define-a-window-in-spark-sql-with-fixed-size-start-with-its-min-val/77188902#77188902) asked about same thing for Spark. Not sure if you can translate directly to Postgres/Bigquery (which of these actually is this question about?), but it might provide you some hints.

Comment: I can implement this in either bigquery or postgres.